# Raspberrypi 3 camera port

Tags: camera

I have broken the little tags either side of the port and the camera ribbon will not stay held in. What can I do to make it work

Comment: You could tape it in place or use something like blu tack, probably best that whatever you use is non-conductive. If you are feeling really bold you could swap out the connector for a new one, but that's at the risk of damaging your Pi.

Answer (score 3):

There should be two Flexible Flat Cable (FFC) connectors on the Pi. One is used for the camera and the other is used for external displays. Both connectors are identical, and use a latching push-in plastic piece to wedge the flat cable against the connector pins. It sounds like you've broken this piece on your camera connector.

It should be possible, with *extreme caution*, to simultaneously depress the latching pieces at either side of the display connector (the non-broken one) and lift it off. This won't be easy, and you'll need steady hands and small tools. If you manage to successfully lift it off it should be a direct replacement for the broken part on the camera connector. Similarly removing the broken camera connector hinge and replacing it with the piece from the display connector should solve the problem.

[image: Pi FFC connector hinge latches]

Alternatively you could try to track down the exact component used on the Pi, buy a couple (similar things are pretty cheap) and cannibalise it for the plastic hinge. I've had a poke about and I can't find an exact replica or a part number. You're looking for a 1mm pitch, 15 pin FFC or Flexible Printed Circuit (FPC) connector.

Comment: Apparently this is Molex 54548-2271 (found somewhere on Raspberry Pi forums).

Answer (score 1):

Hot glue might be your best bet.

Comment: I love hot glue!